# How do I connect multiple UIButtons to a single IBAction and receive events?

Tags: ios, swift

I created a function in my view controller like this:

```
    @IBAction func dayOfWeekActions(sender: UIButton) {

    }
```

I then connected that function to multiple buttons, which appropriately connected the "Touch Up Inside" actions to it (the Connections inspector shows the correct connections).

However, when I do tap the buttons, this function never gets called.

Why doesn't the function ever get called? What have I missed when connecting this all together?

Comment: That should work. How do you know it's not called? Do the buttons show the dimming when you touch them?

Comment: The buttons do dim. However, I can tell it's not getting called because it never hits the line (nor anything inside the function) when a breakpoint is set. And for caveman debugging, I also verified that a `println()` inside does nothing.

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong then, since it probably has something to do with the connections you made in IB. There's nothing special about connecting multiple buttons to one method. It should work the same way as if you had only connected one.

Comment: FWIW, I also ensured that I'm not doing anything basically dumb: the scene is connected to the correct view controller (other controls in the view  call their IBAction functions), etc.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll review and if anything comes up, I'll be sure to answer my own question.

Comment: Well, it turns out that something's jacked with my Xcode. My buddy ran the project in her Xcode and it worked perfectly. Things are so messed up, somehow, that it won't even top on breakpoints in mine, but does just fine in hers.

Answer (score 0):

I remember experiencing this issue myself. I couldn't find a way to use IB to do this (but I remember in a previous incarnation of Xcode this was possible)

The alternative is to connect all buttons to an Outlet Collection then in viewDidLoad iterate across the collection while addTarget:action:forControlEvents: to each button.

```
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!

override func loadView() {
  super.loadView()
  for button in buttons {
    button.addTarget(self, action: "dayOfWeekActions:", forControlEvent: .TouchUpInside)
  }


}
```

Comment: Tried this, but unfortunately the results are the same. Thanks for your suggestion, though. I must have something fundamentally wrong with the project and just can't see it.

Comment: Sounds like you might have something blocking the buttons?